# Usergrid Build Error

Tags: usergrid, mbaas

while I'm trying to build Usergrid, I'm coming across the following error.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.752 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-16T01:02:23+03:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project usergrid-rest: Could not resolve depen
dencies for project org.apache.usergrid:usergrid-rest:war:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failur
e to find org.apache.usergrid:usergrid-java-client:jar:0.0.10-SNAPSHOT in file:/
/C:\usergrid-master\stack\rest/../m2/repository was cached in the local reposito
ry, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of local-depend
encies has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException

C:\usergrid-master\stack>mvn clean install -rf :usergrid-rest
```

Any solution ?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to build `sdks/java` first in order to build the `stack`.

```
cd C:\usergrid\sdks\java
mvn install
cd ..\..\stack
mvn install -DskipTests=true
```

Comment: There isn't a POM file in that directory anymore. The README.md file states: The Java SDK code has been moved into its own repository and can be found 
at https://github.com/apache/usergrid-java.

Comment: Okay so I ran into the same issue. So I copied https://github.com/apache/usergrid-java to \usergrid\sdks\java and followed your instructions. Now I get `
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project awscluster: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.usergrid:awscluster:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.usergrid:usergrid-rest:war:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]`